# Dojo - convert XML to JSON?

Tags: xml, json, dojo

Simple question:

I am querying a Webservice, which returns XML (this cannot be changed), using javascript (Dojo) but I'd rather deal with JSON than XML.

So, is there a Dojo library that will convert either:

a) An XML string to JSON?
or
b) An XML Document to JSON?

I've had a look but not found anything which seems a bit strange...

Thanks

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem (at least if you want to do it cleanly and safely). The formats don't map 1:1 onto each other. JSON distinguishes between an property with a scalar value and a property with an array value of length 1. XML distinguishes between attributes and child elements (and can have attributes and elements with the same name). Library recommendations for Stackoverflow are off-topic anyway.

Comment: "Library recommendations for Stackoverflow are off-topic anyway" - I find this strange as most development work these days revolves around the use of preexisting libraries. Point noted tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this strange and ended up coding my own in about 50 lines and the only difficulty I recall is choosing a convention for repeated nodes.  I was working with simple xml (no comments, no text nodes).

When presented with something like this:

```
<xml><foo>foo1</foo><foo a="a">foo2</foo></xml>
```

I did this or something very similar:

```
{ xml: [{ foo: {_v: "foo1", a: "a"} }, {foo: {_v: "foo2"} }] }
```

I'm sure you're aware of more robust solutions:

https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json/blob/master/lib/xml2json.js

https://code.google.com/p/x2js/source/browse/xml2json.js?r=ebaa2598910f0750ff8593a2b259074f52aa25b9

Comment: I had looked at xml2json but for some reason I thought it required jQuery. Looking at the source from your second link this appears not to be case. Accepting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where have you looked? Dojo has a [xml parser](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/xml.html). I don't think it would be much work converting the parsed xml to [json](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/json.html).